# How to Check for valid input c#

Tags: c#, winforms, isnullorempty

i'm trying to make this method like, if you haven't pressed the correct value a message box will show and when you press the messagebox it will return and you have to try to put the rigth values in again and so on. And if the field is null or empty is has to give =0.. If i press ex. e2 it has to pup up with the message box??

have tried this one without the else if.. and the messagebox vil not disappear? please help

```
    public int playerOneDart1Value;
    public int calculateDart1()
    {



        if (player == "t1" || player == "T1" || player == "3")
        {
            playerOneDart1Value = 3;
        }

       else if (player == null) or empty??
        {
            playerOneDart1Value = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not valid input");
            return calculateDart1();


        }

        return playerOneDart1Value;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah its a static method called `String.IsNullOrEmpty( string )`

Comment: Also, `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` if you want non-empty strings with spaces to count

Comment: not quite sure what your asking

Comment: An aside, your method is doing like 3 different things at the same time.  You are validating inputs, doing behind the scenes number conversions, and also displaying messages.  Perhaps you should break these into separate methods to help prevent these things from interfering with each other.

Comment: that code won't compile `else if (player == null) or empty?? { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `return calculateDart1();` straight after showing the message box, so the user never has a chance to alter the input, before the check being made again, and showing the message box.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function `calculateDart1` recursively and so the reason the messagebox won't disappear is that `MessageBox.Show("not valid input");` is being called over and over again.

Comment: ahead of me by aprox 3 seconds. Touché ;)

Comment: @Drew R Thanks! it help me alot, new to c# :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `calculateDart1()` right after the `MessageBox` prompt which results in an endless loop which makes the user unable to provide new input. For your "null or empty" requirement, you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` which returns `true` if a string is either `null` or empty.

```
public int playerOneDart1Value;
public int calculateDart1()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(player))
    {
        playerOneDart1Value = 0;
    }
    else if (player == "t1" || player == "T1" || player == "3")
    {
        playerOneDart1Value = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not valid input");
        //you can use something like a negative value to indicate invalid input
        playerOneDart1Value = -1;
    }
    return playerOneDart1Value;
}
```